# AngularJS: ng-repeat with associative array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to implement a simple ng-repeat with associative array but with no success so far. I have the following data:

```
[1: "Test", 2: "Second Test", 7: "Another Test"]
```

I have this saved in a variable called `participantsList` which gets send to the HTML. I'm using `$parent` because I have a wrapping HTML page and the one that contains the `ng-repeat` is rendered within it. Here's the HTML code:

```
<select class="form-control" id="participant_drop_down_list" ng-model="$parent.participant_id" required>
   <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in $parent.participantsList track by key" value="{{key}}">{{value}}</option>
</select>
```

If I don't have the `track by key` added to the declaration I get the duplicate key error which is odd. With that added, however, I get no errors but the following HTML is actually rendered:

```
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" id="participant_drop_down_list" ng-model="$parent.participant_id" required="">
    <option value="? undefined:undefined ?"></option>
    <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in $parent.participantsList track by key" value="0" class="ng-binding ng-scope"></option>
    <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in $parent.participantsList track by key" value="1" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Test</option>
    <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in $parent.participantsList track by key" value="2" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Second Test</option>
    <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in $parent.participantsList track by key" value="3" class="ng-binding ng-scope"></option>
    <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in $parent.participantsList track by key" value="4" class="ng-binding ng-scope"></option>
    <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in $parent.participantsList track by key" value="5" class="ng-binding ng-scope"></option>
    <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in $parent.participantsList track by key" value="6" class="ng-binding ng-scope"></option>
    <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in $parent.participantsList track by key" value="7" class="ng-binding ng-scope">RT</option>
</select>
```

Obviously, I don't want the empty options there, I'm interested only in the three that I have initially but I have no idea where things are going south right now. Am I tracking by the wrong value or is the data not formed correctly? Any tips will be welcomed, thank you!

P.S. Is there a way to get rid off the first option with the undefined value as well?

Comment: Look at ng-option instead of ng-repeat.

Comment: data structure shown is not valid javascript or json. Check console for errors or show proper structure used

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis Thank you! The ng-options did the trick when I used this: `ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in $parent.participantsList"`

Answer (score 0):

As the comments state, the answer would be to use [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) instead of `ng-repeat`:

```
<select class="form-control" id="participant_drop_down_list" ng-model="$parent.participant_id" required>
   <option ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in $parent.participantsList>{{value}}</option>
</select>
```